# Creating related records in a single POST request

Tags: python, django, tastypie

Using tastypie, how would I go about creating a record and several related records in a single POST request?

For example, I have these two resources:

```
class SongResource(ModelResource):
    playlists = fields.ToManyField('playlists.api.resources.PlaylistResource', 'playlist_set', related_name = "song", full=True)

    class Meta:
        queryset = Song.objects.all();
        resource_name = 'song'
        authorization = Authorization()


class PlaylistResource(ModelResource):
    song = fields.ToOneField(SongResource, 'song', full=True)

    class Meta:
        queryset = Playlist.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'playlist'
        authorization = Authorization()
```

I'd like to create a new playlist and its songs in one shot using a post request with data, something like this:

```
    var data = JSON.stringify({
        'name': 'My playlist.',
        'songs': [{'title': 'Song 1'}, {'title': 'Song 2'}, {'title': 'Song 3'}]
    });
```

That doesn't work. I'm told, "The 'song' field was given data that was not a URI, not a dictionary-alike and does not have a 'pk' attribute". Is it possible to insert a record in one one fell swoop like this or do I need to send separate requests for the playlist and each song?

Answer (score 1):

Just from playing around with it very, very quickly (and I'm new to tastypie so take this with a grain of salt) - I think you can do this by overriding the obj_create() method inside your resource. Something like this:

```
class SomeResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        # yadda yadda

    def obj_create(self, bundle, request, **kwargs):
        print "hey we're in object create"
        # do something with bundle.data, this will have your songs in it
        return super(SomeResource, self).obj_create(bundle, request, **kwargs)
```

Comment: I was hoping it could be done automatically but that could definitely work. Thanks I'll give it a try today.

Answer (score 0):

You want to do something like this:

```
curl --dump-header - -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST --data '{"name":"playlist_name", "field2":"value2", "song": ["/api/v1/song/1/"]}' http://localhost:8000/api/v1/playlist/
```

Good luck!

Comment: But doesn't that assume a song has already been created? I need to create the playlist and song at the same time.

Comment: I that case do this (I think): curl --dump-header - -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST --data '{"name":"playlist_name", "field2":"value2", "song": ["title":"Song Title","Field2":"field2",...]}' http://localhost:8000/api/v1/playlist/

Comment: That's more or less what I'm doing in my JSON example above, except that I need to pass multiple songs, and it looks like your JSON only passes one song, right?

Comment: Oops, I left off the dictionary brackets in my previous comment.  You can pass multiple songs like this: curl --dump-header - -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST --data '{"name":"playlist_name", "field2":"value2", "song": [{"title":"Song Title 1","Field2":"field2"},{"title":"Song Title 2","Field2":"field2"}]}' localhost:8000/api/v1/playlist

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm already doing as far as I can tell, but it does not seem to be working. See my JSON example above. Isn't that the same, or am I missing something?

Comment: I've heard that using full=True causes problems with related records.  Try disabling those per the comments to this answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11443718/382374